# Setting LinearLayout's Visibility After Animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout which I create in my xml file with its visibility set to `Gone`. I then showIt using an Animation and thats fine.

I fade out my `LinearLayout` using an `AlphaAnimation` and this works fine.

**My Problem**

The problem however is when I listen to the animation using an `AnimationListener` and the `onAnimationEnd` method is called, it doesn't set the visibility of my `LinearLayout` to `GONE` as I can still click the `ImageButtons` that are inside it which is how I know they're still there.

here is my xml with my LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/photoOptionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="@color/gpsBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/displayShareBtn"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/share"
            android:contentDescription="Share the picture"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/displayDiscardBtn"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless.Small"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/contentdiscard"
            android:contentDescription="Discard Picture"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my fade out method along with the listener.

```
AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1.0F, 0.0F);
    alpha.setDuration(PhotoDisplayFragment.FADE_DURATION); // Make animation instant
    alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Tell it to persist after the animation ends
    // And then on your layout
    final LinearLayout temp = this._photoOptionsBar;
    alpha.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            temp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
    this._photoOptionsBar.startAnimation(alpha);
```

**My Question**

How do I set the visibility of the my `LinearLayout` to `GONE` after the animation ends?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: remove the setFillAfter. The way you choose is correct

Comment: I need the setFillAfter so that when I want to fade it in again its alpha is 0

Comment: Just check the photoOptionsBar visibility and apply the fidein animation. new AlphaAnimation(0.0F, 1.0F);

Comment: @blackbelt write it as answer and will accept. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to `setFillAfter` which  let the animation persist when it is finished. Remove and all will work as expected. If if you need the fade in  animatio check the `_photoOptionsBar` visibilty and if it is gone apply the inverse animation:

```
new AlphaAnimation(0.0F, 1.0F);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final LinearLayout temp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.photoOptionBar);
temp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I can't use findViewByID as I'm not in an Activity I'm in a fragment